# Retrieve objetct with criteria distinct

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I got the follow Entity:

```
public class Item {
   @Id
   private int id;

   @OneToOne
   private Center center;

   @OneToOne
   private Nature nature;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date date;

   @Column(columnDefinition = "Numeric(19,2) default '0.00'")
   private BigDecimal cost;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Status status; //Enumerated

  /**
   * Getters, Setters and some internal logical
  **/
}
```

I'm trying to search differents combinations of `Items` for `center` and `nature`, with `min date` using criteria.

I found how to do it setting `Projection.distinct()` but when I try to retrieve these objects it says it can't cast them on `Item`.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

My criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
criteria
    .add(Restrictions.eq("status", Status.PROCESS))
    .setProjection(Projections.distinct(
            Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("nature"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("center"))
                .add(Projections.min("date"))
                )
            );

  List<Item> items= criteria.list();
```

**Update:**
Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to br.com.okds.ent.Item
    at br.com.okds.cont.Control.reprocess(Control.java:70)
    at br.com.okds.evopweb.ItemBean.reprocessAll(ItemBean.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at br.com.okds.sistemapadao.cont.acesso.AcessControl.doFilter(AcessControl.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Update 2:**

In other question I found I should use something like this:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Item.class));
```

after `Projection.distinct()`, but the problem is all object have `null` values and zero `ids`

Comment: You might want to add 'hibernate' tag to you question, otherwise it is quite non-obvious what it is about from cursory look.

Comment: Please post an [mcve], the expected result, and the result that you're actually getting (including exception/stacktrace if any)